# What's the format for 'Select item B from menu A'

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

When answering a question, is there a preferred StackExchange format for explaining how to do something in a GUI, optionally specifying shortcut keys?

Eg (terse) `Window > Select next tab (cmd-alt-right)`

Or (chatty) From the 'Window' menu, choose the 'Select next tab' option, but it's quicker to use the shortcut key: cmd-alt-right (ctrl-tab works too).

If terse is preferred, is it okay to wrap in backticks to emphasise it's an instruction to the GUI, like you would if it were an instruction to the CLI? Or is that bad form?

I'm asking the StackExchange community about guidelines for posting menu selections in StackOverflow questions, not when explaining things to the world at large.

I found [this request for a markdown syntax for menu selections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193531/what-is-the-markdown-for-menu-options) but I'm not asking for that, just 'Is there a format people generally follow?' for demonstrating menu selections. Seems it would be something quite key for a site that helps people do stuff with computers, often using menu selections!

The OP ended up using *File → Save as...* which I agree stands out enough and looks like something you might see in a GUI textbook.

Comment: In the end...  it doesn't even matter ;-)

Comment: I use a combo of italics and backticks and `<kbd>` tags as needed.

Comment: Your terse format is how I commonly see menu items written. Formatted as code, it has the advantage of being distinguishable from the rest of the text too; easy to scan for. As far as an SE guideline goes, do what you think conveys the meaning the clearest.